# Swift. После прохождения блока do catch обнуляется значение переменной

Tags: json, swift, url

Имеем такое - разбираю работу с API. Получаем данные, а потом парсим json. но вот после окончания блока DO CATCH пропадают данные из переменной

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct ImageJson:Codable{
    let id:String
    let author:String
    let width:Int
    let height: Int
    let url:String
    let download_url:String
}

class APiHelper{
    var images:[ImageJson] = []
    
    func getImageArray(){
        let apiString = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list"
        guard let apiURL = URL(string: apiString) else {
            fatalError("fatal Error")
        }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: apiURL) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do{
                self.images = try JSONDecoder().decode([ImageJson].self, from: data)
                //вот здесь в переменной есть данные - массив 
                print(self.images)
            } catch{
                print("Произошла ошибка")
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        //а вот здесь уже нет
        //и соответсвенно не сохраняется в self.images
        print(self.images)
    }
}
```

Подскажите более опытные в чем дело и что я делаю не так

Comment: Используйте замыкания для получения асинхронного результата https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1325623/204219

Comment: @schmidt9 с замыканиями я знаком,и использую в передаче данных между контроллерами, но вот как здесь это сделать?

Comment: Верните images в замыкании, по аналогии как это сделано в ответе по ссылке

Comment: @schmidt9 там в коде нет этой аналогии, просто передается currentData в замыкание, но самого кода обработки в замыкании нет, поэтому и уточняю. А если я хочу сделать такое вот замыкание var closure:(([ImageJson]) -> Void)? = { jsonArr in
        self.images = jsonArr
    }

Comment: то я получаю ошибку Cannot find 'self' in scope, а если убрать self - Cannot use instance member 'images' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с вашим кодом, аналогичный примеру [в другом моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325438/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-api-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5/1325623#1325623)

```
class APiHelper{
    
    class func getImageArray(_ completion: @escaping ([ImageJson]) -> Void){
        let apiString = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list"
        guard let apiURL = URL(string: apiString) else {
            fatalError("fatal Error")
        }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: apiURL) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do{
                let images = try JSONDecoder().decode([ImageJson].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(images)
                }
            } catch{
                print("Произошла ошибка")
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}

APiHelper.getImageArray { images in
    print(images)
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже разобрался с Вашим примером, не успел ответить